# mfmailcomposeviewcontroller crashing on iOS 6

Tags: cocoa, ios6

Normally, when I use mfmailcomposeviewcontroller like so:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{

        MFMailComposeViewController *mcvc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mcvc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mcvc setSubject:@"Check out these diamonds!"];

        [self presentModalViewController:mcvc animated:YES];
        [mcvc release];
}
```

And I am now getting this error on iOS 6:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/ericshorr/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/7904C2AD-23E1-4211-B5FA-A1F03CB3A875/SDE Group Diamonds.app> (loaded)' with name 'MFMailComposeInternalViewController''
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to setup a mail account in your iPad to be able to send mails in iOS 6. Go to *Mail, Contacts, Calenders* in Settings, then add a mail account.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently where I added a category to UIViewController, so that I could override init and append an additional modifier to the nib name. Like so...

```
self = [self initWithNibName:[nibName stringByAppendingString:@"_modifier"] bundle:nil];
```

Although the UIViewController category was not #imported in the class that was attempting to launch the MFMailComposeViewController, it was imported in the header of a different class that was being added as a child view controller. Hence, the MFMailComposeViewController was trying to find a NIB with name:  MFMailComposeInternalViewController_modifier.

Seems obvious in hindsight but this was a nightmare to catch, so I thought I'd add it here as a possible solution, for anyone else who runs in to a similar situation.